# Change x-axis interval on zoom - HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This is how my date format from JSON file looks: http://jsfiddle.net/6roz4ya8/

I would like my chart to show only hour and minute on x-axis in normal view  (I can trim, just how to go about in highchart), whereas minutes and seconds when zoomed. I understand we could use tick positioner when  type="datetime". How do I do the same for 'categories: dateFromJsonFile'(i.e. if using date on x-axis from json file)

For eg: If '2022-07-15T13:57:54.4919219+03:00', I want 13:57 to be shown in general (unzoomed normal view) and 57:54 to be shown when zoomed

```
xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    //I need to set categories to timeData, as this timeData comes from Json
    // categories: timeData, 
    type: "datetime",
    labels: {
      rotation: 270
    },
}
```

Below is how I want it to be. Shows one minute interval in normal view, 10 seconds interval on Zoom - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7qj2cLea/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `formatter` function for x-axis labels and return hours and minutes in case of not zoomed chart and minutes and seconds in case of zoomed.

```
const formatTime = time => time > 9 ? time : '0' + time;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: 270,
            formatter: function() {
                const date = new Date(this.value);

                if (this.chart.resetZoomButton) {
                    return formatTime(date.getMinutes()) + ':' + formatTime(date.getSeconds());
                }

                return formatTime(date.getHours()) + ':' + formatTime(date.getMinutes());
            }
        },
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k7nywoad/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter